# Creating an Edit Form with Django Crispy Forms

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-crispy-forms

I'm using Django Crispy Forms to build a form. The form is appearing just how I want it to. I can use the form to create a new object and add it to the database.

However, I'm running into trouble with the editing side of things. My first thought was that I would want to use either a PATCH or PUT form action, but according to the crispy docs (checkout [form_method](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api_helpers.html)) this isn't allowed.

In addition, I'm trying to use the Django-Rest-Framework, the generic class based views, and the mixins. I was trying to use the [UpdateModelMixin](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views#updatemodelmixin), but it seems to require a PATCH or PUT.

Should I not be using Crispy forms? Should I just use a POST method even though I'm only updating a db entry? Totally different approach? There's a number of different bits of code here, let me know if any of it would be helpful to see!